# codeigniter params not working with defined route

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I have defined route for particular URL, but with route params is not working, with same URL without route params is working, here is my URL for that

```
https://XXXX.com/username/post/details/10425/50
```

And its for i have defined below route

```
$route['(:any)/post/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] ='post/details/$1/$2';
```

`10425` and `50` is my 2 params, which is not working for me, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Instead of (:any) have you tried to use (:num)? in the last two like this: $route['(:any)/post/details/(:num)/(:num)'] ='post/details/$1/$2';

Comment: I tried this $route['(:any)/post/(:any)/(:num)/(:num)'] ='post/details/$1/$2';     but it is also not working

Comment: and if you change the (:any) after post to 'details'?

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['(:any)/post/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] ='post/details/$1/$2';
```

Should be :

```
$route['(:any)/post/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] ='post/details/$3/$4';
```

Since it's the 3rd and 4th parameters, not 1st and 2nd.

Comment: No problem, and thanks it's my 1st accepted answer :D